# Where does CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE go in your project?

Tags: python, celery, celerybeat

I've read several pages of Google results multiple times and I'm very confused about how to layout my project. I have managed to get Celerybeat working using the periodic_task decorator, but that is [depreciated and is being removed](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/deprecation.html#modules-to-remove). From what I understand, [the docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/3.0/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries) suggest that CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE is the replacement. I've created a file exactly as shown, but haven't yet figured out:

- How to name it?
- Where to put it?

I find it very hard to find the right way to use Celery in a **non-Django** project.

Answer (score 8):

It's a bit confusing that [the docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/3.0/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries) make it look like your CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE is a separate file. In reality, it's an entry in your app (aka: Celery() instance) config as you can [see it listed here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celerybeat-schedule). So however you get the configuration into your app, that's where it goes.

There are many ways to get the configuration into the app. If you believe "[Explicit is better than implicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)", then you probably want to:

1. Put your config into a module, like `celeryconfig.py`
2. Import the module where your app is define or used. `import celeryconfig`
3. Apply the module object to your app. `app.config_from_object(celeryconfig)`

**Example celeryconfig.py file**

```
from datetime import timedelta

BROKER_URL = "redis://redis.local:6379/0"
BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'fanout_prefix': True, 'fanout_patterns': True, 'visibility_timeout': 480}
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = BROKER_URL

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'addrandom-to-16K-every-2-seconds': {
        'task': 'celery_test.tasks.addrandom', # notice that the complete name is needed
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=2),
        'args': (16000, 42)
    },
}

CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

Trying to put it into a file like `beatschedule.py` and then running `celery -A beatschedule beat` will get you `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery'`

I created [this project](https://github.com/RichardBronosky/celery_test) to demo Celerybeat in action as described in the docs. I believe it does a better job of showing how it all works than reading the docs alone. I also created [this Docker image](https://github.com/RichardBronosky/celery_redis_demo) to make getting it up and running as simple as possible.